# How did he calculate the error in this example?

Tags: analog, math, pll

He found an error of about 18%.

What is the error formula used in this example?

[image: section 1.5.1 of the book Design of PLLs by Behzad Razavi]

From section 1.5.1 of the book *Design of PLLs* by Behzad Razav.

Comment: Ummmm... Equation 1.36 maybe????

Comment: So show what you have considered so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a target value is supposed to be 1.51 units, and you use an actual 1.25 unit thing, then your error is (target - actual) / target = (1.51 - 1.25) / 1.51 = 0.1722.

It appears your textbook rounded that to "about 18%", perhaps by calculating 1.25 / 1.51 = 0.8278, rounding to 0.82, which is 0.18 from 1.00.